# Approximating a Gaussian integral

Tags: real-analysis, normal-distribution, approximation, contour-integration

I have been struggling with an approximation to the following integral
\begin{equation}
\text{p.v.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {e^{-s^2/2v} \over (e^{-2s}- q a)^2} {ds \over \sqrt{2 \pi v}}
\end{equation}

where the parameters $q, a, v$ are positive constants and $0<q \leq 1$. My intention is to find the solution to the following equation

\begin{equation}
{1 \over a^2} = \text{p.v.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {e^{-s^2/2v} \over (e^{-2s}- q a)^2} {ds \over \sqrt{2 \pi v}}
\end{equation}

I tried expanding ${e^{-s^2/2v} \over (e^{-2s}- q a)^2}$ around $s=0$ and $s=-{1 \over 2}\ln{qa}$, but expansion around the 2nd point gives rise to an expression of the form
$$
{C_{-2} \over (s + {1 \over 2}\ln qa)^2} + {C_{-1} \over s + {1 \over 2}\ln qa} + C_0 + C_{1} (s + {1 \over 2}\ln qa) + C_{2} (s + {1 \over 2}\ln qa)^2
$$
Integration the above expression around a small interval $(-{1\over 2}\ln qa - \epsilon, -{1\over 2}\ln qa + \epsilon)$ gives a divergent result.

Plotting the integral as a function of $a$ for fixed $q$ and $v$ (preferably in log-log scale), one can see that the function has many spikes and many intersections with $1/a^2$. Could you share an idea of a possible approximation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a\,q\ne0$, the integral does not converge.

Let $s^*=-\ln(a\,q)/2$. The denominator of the integrand vanishes when $s=s^*$. Close to $s^*$ we have
$$
(e^{-2s}-a\,q)^2\sim (s-s^*)^2,
$$
meaning
$$
\lim_{s\to s^*}\frac{(e^{-2s}-a\,q)^2}{(s-s^*)^2}=c\ne0.
$$
Finally, $(s-s^*)^{-2}$ is not integrable on any neighborhood of $s^*$.

Comment: Could you give more details?

Comment: @user104509, there is a pole of even order in the integrand located at where $e^{-2s} = qa$, so the integral diverges.  The principal value integral will diverge as well.

Comment: See details in the edited answer.

Comment: No, it does not. And you did not mention principal values in your question. In this case they do not exist: se Antonio's comment.

Comment: So one can say expanding around the pole is a very bad idea. Is there way to approximate the integral over $(-\infty, \infty)$?

Comment: Yes : $\infty$.

Comment: Compute $\int_{|x|>\epsilon} dx/x^2$ and let $\epsilon\to0$.